# Sign up form: if statement

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making a sign up form and I wrote this where it checks the password to see if it meets these conditions:

> Should be at least 5 - 15 characters
>
> Should contain a number OR an uppercase

And that's it! Now, first, it checks if the field is empty, and if not, it checks the length. Now, here's my question. Trying this code, it appears to always consider the if statement FALSE and goes straight to its else block and execute it. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public void PWStrength(String password)
{
    password = StudentPW.getText().toString();
    pwLength = password.length();
    if (password.matches(""))
    {
        final TextView textViewToChange1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyPW);
        textViewToChange1.setText("Please choose a password!");
    }
    else 
    {
        final TextView textViewToChange1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyPW);
        textViewToChange1.setText("");
        if ((pwLength < 5) && (pwLength > 15))
            {           
                final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PWvalid);
                textViewToChange.setText("Your password should be between 5 - 15 characters");
            }
        else 
            {
                final TextView textViewToChange3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PWvalid);
                textViewToChange3.setText("");
                if (!upperCase(password) && lowerCase(password) && !Numbers(password))
                {
                    final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PWvalid);
                    textViewToChange.setText("Your password should contain at least 1 uppercase or 1 number");
                }
                else
                {
                    final TextView textViewToChange4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PWvalid);
                    textViewToChange4.setText("");
                }

            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING at us.. :-/

Comment: Would an input filter be the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear which `if` statement you mean, but there's a problem with this one:

```
if ((pwLength < 5) && (pwLength > 15))
```

See if you can think of a single number that is both less than 5 and greater than 15 at the same time.

You probably meant `||`, not `&&`.

To make your code a little less cluttered, remember that this length-test will also handle an empty password (length 0), so you can take that other test out altogether.

Comment: It is actually as simple as that. Didn't even think twice about it when I wrote it and didn't think it would be my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you want `password.equals("")` not `password.matches("")` to check if the string is empty

Comment: But password.matches("") works with me in this case.

Comment: .matches uses a "regular expression", it is faster & better documented to use .equals for a simple comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText yourEditTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
yourEditTextName.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener l{
String yourtext = (String) yourEditTextName.getText();
String yourtextlowercase = yourtext.toLowerCase();
if(your text != yourtextlowercase || containsSpecialCharacter(yourtext))
//do what you want

});
```

## The Meathod

> public boolean containsSpecialCharacter(String s) {
>       return (s == null) ? false : s.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]"); }